# How do I select atoms using mdtraj_topology when creating a CV?

Tags: python, openpathsampling

I am adding a new collective variable (CV) that I will use to calculate a path density with OpenPathSampling. I played around a bit with the CVs and I have one error that I'm not sure how to fix. I'm hoping you can help me with it.
I am trying to select the atoms directly with residue number and atom name from the topology to calculate the CV.
To do this, I have a function to calculate the CV and then I've written a function to wrap this in the CollectiveVariable object.
The `topology.select` seems to be the issue and that means I'm not calling the data properly. How do I make this selection?

The function to calculate the CV:

```
def rolling_angle(traj, backbone, rollingbase):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    traj : mdtraj.Trajectory
        trajectory to analyze
    rolling_atoms : RollingAtoms
        info on which atoms to use; returned from get_baserolling_atoms
    """
    def normalize(vector):
        norms = np.linalg.norm(vector, axis=1)
        return vector / norms.reshape(len(norms), 1)
    def arccos_based_angle(v1, v2):
        return np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(v1, v2), -1, 1))
    def atan2_based_angle(v1, v2):
        return np.arctan2(np.cross(v1, v2), np.dot(v1, v2))

    # get the vector associated with the rolling base
    bp_v21 = traj.xyz[:,rollingbase[0]] - traj.xyz[:,rollingbase[1]]
    bp_v23 = traj.xyz[:,rollingbase[2]] - traj.xyz[:,rollingbase[1]]
    bp_vector = normalize(np.cross(bp_v21, bp_v23))

    # get the vector associated with the backbone
    bb_vector = traj.xyz[:,backbone[1]] - traj.xyz[:,backbone[0]]
    bb_vector = normalize(bb_vector)
    # calculate angle
    return np.degrees([
        atan2_based_angle(bb, bp)
        for (bb, bp) in zip(bb_vector, bp_vector)
    ])
```

The function to wrap in object:

```
def rolling_base(snapshot):
    topology = snapshot.topology
    backbone = topology.select("resid 5 10 and name P")
    rollingbase = topology.select("resid 3 and name N7 N3 N1")
    return rolling_angle(traj, backbone, rollingbase)

new_cv = paths.CoordinateFunctionCV('rolling_base',rolling_base)
```

Plotting the CV:

```
path_density = paths.PathDensityHistogram(cvs=[d_WC, new_cv],
                                          left_bin_edges=(0.2,0.2),
                                          bin_widths=(0.01,0.01))
path_dens_counter = path_density.histogram(trajs[:5])
```

Comment: Thanks for transferring the question from email over to here!

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you so much for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the error you're seeing right now, the problem is that your function requires an `mdtraj.Trajectory` as input, but you're wrapping it with a `paths.CoordinateFunctionCV`, which provides the wrapped function with OpenPathSampling trajectory. Wrapping with a `paths.MDTrajFunctionCV` should fix that error: it converts to MDTraj.

However, there's also a more straightforward way to achieve the same result, *without* creating the extra function.

### The current error

It looks like the function `rolling_base` is designed to take an MDTraj trajectory as input, not an OPS snapshot. MDTraj provides the `select` functionality; OPS does not. In that case, you should wrap it with `MDTrajCVFunction` instead of `CoordinateCVFunction` when you create `new_cv`. This automatically handles the process of translating between OPS and MDTraj, so the input your function sees is an MDTraj trajectory. Note that `MDTrajFunctionCV` also requires a topology object as input (where the topology is the OPS-wrapped version of the MDTraj topology, which you may have already created for your engine.)

### Another (probably easier) approach

You've added an extra function, `rolling_base`, that exists to "freeze" some of the parameters to the `rolling_angle` function. This isn't necessary -- CVs in OPS can do this for you. You just need to pass the extra arguments as keywords (i.e., with an explicit `=`) when you make the CV.

Wrapping with an `MDTrajFunctionCV` (and assuming an OPS-wrapped MDTraj topology in `topology`):

```py
topology = ...  # OPS wrapper for an MDTraj topology; probably have this in engine
mdtraj_topology = topology.mdtraj
new_cv = paths.MDTrajFunctionCV(
   'rolling_base'
   rolling_angle,
   topology=topology,
   backbone=mdtraj_topology.select("resid 5 10 and name P"),
   rollingbase=mdtraj_topology.select("resid 3 and name N7 N3 N1")
)
```

This will "freeze" the parameters `backbone` and `rollingbase` when the function `rolling_angle` is called. You can find some simplified examples of this in the [OPS documentation on creating CVs](http://openpathsampling.org/latest/topics/creating_collective_variables.html#generalizing-your-cv-function). The idea is similar to [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from the Python standard library (discussed with examples [here](https://siddharth1.medium.com/partial-functions-in-python-functools-partial-with-applications-and-examples-b65114ba82fb)). Note that, unlike `functools.partial`, with OPS CVs, you must always specify the keyword name (i.e., you need to include `backbone=` and `rollingbase=`).

### Checking that your new CV works

After you've made your new CV, it's best to check that it works on some simple example data. It looks like `trajs` is a list of OPS trajectories; what I would do is (assuming (1) you're in a Jupyter notebook; (2) have imported matplotlib as `plt`, and (3) `trajs` is a list of trajectories):

```py
plt.plot(new_cv(trajs[0]))
```

That should give you `new_cv` on the y axis, frame number on the x axis, for trajectory 0. Is it reasonable? If not:

1. Double-check the "frozen" variables in your CV. In this case, check that your selections have the number of atoms you expect, and that your have the right topology. It looks like the function expects 2 integers for `backbone` (atom indices to create a vector) and 3 integers for `rollingbase` (atom indices to create a vector normal to the plane defined by the atoms). Is that what your selections return? You can get the `topology` for a snapshot from `snapshot.engine.topology`.
2. Double-check that the function itself gives reasonable result. This looks like a function that has already been tested against an MDTraj CV, but you can create an MDTraj trajectory from an OPS trajectory with `trajectory.to_mdtraj()`. Then directly check whether you get reasonable results from the `rolling_angle` function.

Comment: +10 and thank you for encouraging the user to move the question from email to here! This way if others in the future have the same question, rather than writing the same email dozens of times, hopefully all future users will be able to find this easily: at least I know the level of Search Engine Optimization implemented in Stack Exchange is far better than what most of us could have done on our own personal websites, but if others email you then don't hesitate to direct them here again!